# How can one send a .tar archive on ssh witouth a temporary file? What is the “-f -” option in tar?

Tags: tar

How can I make the compression and decompression of an archive via ssh with tar command, without creating a temporary file:

I've an exemple:

**ScriptClient.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cf - myFile.txt | ssh $IP_SERVER ./ScriptServer.sh
```

**ScriptServer.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -x -C ~/backups/ -f -
```

These code snippet is not mine, and I don’t understand how the `-f -` works in the tar command, the man page is useless.

Answer (score 1):

With `-f archive.tar`, `tar -c` would write to the archive, `tar -x` would extract from it. `-f -` is a special syntax which means "write to stdout" (if creating) or "read from stdin" (if extracting).

This allows to use `tar` in pipes. The client command pipes `tar` to `ssh`. On the remote side SSH server runs `./ScriptServer.sh` and pushes incoming stream to its stdin. `tar -f -` inside the script reads this stream.

You're right that `-f -` is not documented in `man 1 tar` (at least in manuals I read). Without `-f` the tool should use stdout or stdin anyway. Few other tools support `-` as a special "filename" to explicitly point to stdout or stdin; I suppose the support of `-f -` in `tar` is just a compliance to this semi-standard.

Answer (score 1):

> I don’t understand how the `-f -` works in the tar command, the man page is useless.

Which `man` page are you looking at? The one from the command line of your system via `man tar` or something else? [Checking this online man page for `tar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar)—as well [as this one](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tar/)—shows the following:

```
-f, --file=ARCHIVE
use archive file or device ARCHIVE
```

So the `-f` would read the input from a specific file… But what then is the `-` after the `-f`? It sure as hell is not a file. That is basically a special character telling the command—in this case—to get the the data from `stdin` (standard input)… And that `stdin` comes from the first script piping the output—via the `|` pipe via SSH to the receiving script on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without creating script on receiver side.
To transfer files via uncompressed flow from local to remote unix:

```
LocalDir="./"
LocalFile="myFile.txt"
RemoteIP="192.168.1.1"
RemoteDir="~/backups/"

cd "$LocalDir"
tar -cf - "$LocalFile" | ssh $RemoteIP "cd '$RemoteDir'; tar -xf -"
```

POSIX Tar not compresses files, only concatenates. 
Also you may add light compression in such way

```
tar -cf - "$LocalFile" | gzip -1 | \
   ssh $RemoteIP "cd '$RemoteDir'; gzip -cd | tar -xf -"
```

I do not recommend you to add deep compression due to larger time of transferring.

If you want one-liner, here it is:

```
tar -cf - myFile.txt | gzip -1 | ssh 192.168.1.1 "cd backups; gzip -cd | tar -xf -"
```

Tested to transfer file from RHEL6 to Solaris11 and backwards from Solaris to RHEL.

Answer (score -1):

The first command "tar -cf -" will create the tar to standard output (stdout) instead of a regular file.

This will be sent as stdin through ssh, and used as such by server-script.

See also : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/ and https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/working-stdin-and-stdout